# colors from graphic card gets sometime inverted

Tags: 12.04, graphics, radeon, tv

Colors from graphic card gets sometime inverted. When I start Ubuntu 12.04 its just fine, but sometimes after some time the colors get inverted. I use a 40" lcd-tv as a monitor, and if I cahnge the cannel and then turn it back its ok again for some time and then it happend again.

I have a "Sapphire Radeon HD5450 DDR3 HDMI 1GB" and a 50HZ SONY TV.

I have a dual boot so it happens the same in my Windows 8, I have a nother computer connected to my TV and I have never had a problem like that earlier.

Comment: "I have a dual boot so it happens the same in my Windows 8" suggests that the problem is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: But do you think the problem is the driver or the card? Or can it be the cable?

Comment: If you experience the same behavior in Windows, the problem can't be in the driver, unless the same bug somehow affects the Windows drivers, which is unlikely. To diagnose the problem, I'd try swapping things one at a time - replace the cable, see if the problem persist; try using HDMI or VGA instead of DVI; try connecting the machine to another monitor/TV; try replacing the video card.

Comment: thnx ill try that

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing exactly the same problem.

But since i thought to be sure that i did not have this problem with the standard linux video driver, I started experimenting with the settings in the Catalyst Control Center.
What I've come up with is the setting for the **Pixel Format** (only available when using the hdmi I believe).

I have now set it to **Full RGB 4:4:4** and my problems are gone...(it was YCbCr 4:4:2).

Hope this will help others, since this problem was driving me crazy.